# My brackets and parathensis started showing as multicolored in VS Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

For some reason my brackets and parenthesis started showing is multicolored rather than white which I find annoying(see top image compared to bottom) I went threw all the theme color settings and can't seem to get it back that way) I'm not sure what changed.

[image: NOW]

[image: Before]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Colour change to the brackets happen when you upgrade your VS Code to version 1.67.0.

I had 1.65.2 earlier (see attached image) and updated to 1.67.0 (auto update). Now the colors have changed. If you want to see white colour for your brackets, the best suggestion is to downgrade the VS Code version to 1.65 or below, but I will not recommend that since every update contains a bugfix for VS Code.

See more from VS Code April update April 2022 (version 1.67):

[Bracket pair colorization enabled by default](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_67#_bracket-pair-colorization-enabled-by-default)

Regards,
Manoj

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this new feature using `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false,`.